# Kentico override robots meta tag

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

According to the [Kentico Documentation](https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/configuring-kentico/search-engine-optimization/managing-robots-txt), Kentico automatically adds the following tag when I exclude the page from search:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
```

But I need it to be `"noindex,follow"`

I've tried removing it in my canonical webpart under the `OnPreRender` method but Kentico is somehow adding the robots tag after that event.

I can't override it using googlebots as google will still take the more restrictive tag.

I don't mind editing the kentico code but a search of "noindex,nofollow" or "robots" in the solution doesn't find anything.

Does anyone know how I can remove or edit this tag?

I'm using K12SP Portal Engine for the record.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using portal engine, on the search page  go to Properties > Navigation > Search & SEO and uncheck the Exclude from search checkbox. This will manage your "noindex" value

Tho manage your "nofollow" value go to Settings > URLs & SEO and uncheck this box "Use NOFOLLOW for user links", this should get you the results you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Brendan, according to Kentico, the "Use NOFOLLOW for user links" setting does the following:
"If enabled, the system will instruct crawlers (robots) not to follow links posted by users on forums, message boards or in blog comments. This is achieved by including the <strong>rel="nofollow"</strong> attribute in the output code of the given link tags."

Thus I still get "noindex,nofollow"